# Redux Framework - How to use the redux/validate/{opt_name}/class/{field.validate} filter

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I'm working on a custom field extension and all I have left is to include a validator for that field. I figured I'd need to use the `redux/validate/{opt_name}/class/{field.validate}` filter, but I have no clue whatsoever what I need to replace the `{field.validate}` with. I tried the field name, but did not work.

The redux support tells me this is premium support (?) which is kinda insane, the documentation does NOT explain what the `{field.validate}` is referring to, and I think that shouldn't be premium support...

Anyhow, is there anyone who knows how to use this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux here.

{field.validate} would be the validation class you specified in the field.

So whatever you called it (field=> array('validate' => 'reallyCoolValidation') you'd replace with reallyCoolValidation.  ;)

Comment: Okey. That explains the field.validate. Is there a way to have the custom field to force a validation on it? i have some operations that needs to be done and reorganize the values before save, and would be perfect if that functionality was in the custom field extension

Comment: With a custom field, you can either make a custom validation that goes with it, or make your own save hook filter additions.  ;)

Comment: My intention is to create a validation that goes with it, and preferably not required to set in the field array.

Comment: Then you need a /save filter probably built into the extension class, not the field class.